# Shadow is not visible around the UIView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have created a stack of circle `UIViews`(Circles inside a circle)using `CAShapeLayer`. [image: Here is what I have done currently]

Now I want to add shadows for every circle. It should be a drop shadow around the each circles. So I did like this.

```
func setCircleShadow(circle:Circle)
{
    circle.layer.shadowColor=UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.0/255, green: 0.0/255, blue: 0.0/255, alpha: 0.14).cgColor
    circle.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: circle.frame.size.width, height: circle.frame.size.height)
    circle.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    circle.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
    circle.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```

In my `UIViewController` I am calling this method in this way.

```
for addedcircle in circleStack
    {
        self.view.addSubview(addedcircle)
        let deco=CircleDeco()
        deco.setCircleShadow(circle: addedcircle)

    }
```

But my shadows are not visible around the `UIViews`. Please show me whats the error with my code.

**UPDATE**

Circle class draw method calls this and create circles

```
func drawCircle()
{


    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint.init(x: RDcircleEnum.circleCenterX.getValues(), y: RDcircleEnum.circleCenterY.getValues()), radius: CGFloat(self.innerCircleRadius), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)


    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

    //change the fill color
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    //you can change the stroke color
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    //you can change the line width
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

    self.layer.mask = shapeLayer

}
```

This is how to call above method

```
open func setupCirclestack(parentFrame:CGRect)->[Circle]
{
    var arrayCircles = Array<Any>()
    let arrayColor=[UIColor.green,UIColor.blue,UIColor.red,UIColor.purple,UIColor.orange]
    var currentCircleRadius = CGFloat((UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-60)/2)

    for i in 0..<CircleValues.sharedInstance.numberOfCircles-1
    {

      let circle=self.getInnerCircle(currentFrame: parentFrame) as! Circle
        circle.backgroundColor=UIColor.white//arrayColor[i]
        circle.clipsToBounds=false

        arrayCircles.append(circle)
        circle.innerCircleRadius = currentCircleRadius
        currentCircleRadius = currentCircleRadius - 20
        print("New Radius------\(circle.innerCircleRadius)")


    }
```

Then in my view controller I am adding these circles using a for loop

Comment: try changing the offsets to 
 circle.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 5, height: 5)

Comment: @VinayKumar tried  circle.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 5, height: 5) but no luck :(

Comment: Supply enough code to allow your results to be reproduced.

Comment: another guess is that the color alpha value is too small. Add some more code that would help resolve the issue.

Comment: @matt Pls check the updated part.

Comment: @VinayKumar I tried changing alpha but no luck

Comment: You are saying `let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()`. So you have a layer with zero size. I don't see where you give this layer a frame. There must be more code than this!

Comment: What is this in the for loop: let deco=CircleDeco()
        deco.setCircleShadow(circle: addedcircle) You did not use this deco variable anywhere.

Comment: @matt You can just change the values in let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint.init(x: RDcircleEnum.circleCenterX.getValues(), y: RDcircleEnum.circleCenterY.getValues()), radius: CGFloat(self.innerCircleRadius), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

Comment: @VinayKumar its an instance variable. Created at let deco=CircleDeco() to get to access of the method inside CircleDeco class

Answer (score 0):

Check your views for "clipToBounds". Maybe it's true. switch it to false in each your views.

```
view.clipToBounds = false
```

this parameter cuts all oust of view-bounds